# Django: Get average rating per user

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-models

Given the following, how can I make a query which returns a list of the average rating per user in friendlist?

**models.py**

```py
class Beer(models.Model):
    id = models.BigIntegerField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    ...

class Checkin(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    rating = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=CASCADE)
    ...

class FriendList(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=CASCADE, primary_key=True)
    friend = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name="friends")
```

**database (postgresql)**

| user | beer | rating |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 4.2 |
| 1 | 1 | 3.5 |
| 1 | 1 | 4.0 |
| 2 | 1 | 4.1 |
| 2 | 1 | 3.7 |

My current query to get all friends checkins:

```py
Checkin.objects.filter(beer=1, user__in=friends.friend.all())
```

Which gives me something like:

```py
[{user: 1, rating: 4.2}, {user: 1, rating: 3.5},...,{user: 2, rating: 4.1}...]
```

What I want is:

```py
[{user: 1, avg_rating: 4.1}, {user: 2, avg_rating: 3.8}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It makes more sense to [**`.annotate(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#annotate) the `User` objects, so:

```
from django.db.models import Avg

friends.friend.filter(
    checkin__beer_id=1
).annotate(
    rating=Avg('checkin__rating')
)
```

Where *`checkin__`* is the [**`related_query_name=…`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_query_name) for the `user` from `Checkin` to the `User` model. If you did not specify a `related_query_name=…`, then it will use the value for the [**`related_name=…`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name), and if that one is not specified either, it will use the name of the *source* model in lowercase, so `checkin`.

The `User` objects that arise from this queryset will have an extra attribute `.rating` that contains the *average* `rating` over the `Checkin`s for that `beer_id`.

You can determine the average of these averages with an [**`.aggregate(…)`** call <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#aggregate):

```
from django.db.models import Avg

friends.friend.filter(
    checkin__beer_id=1
).annotate(
    rating=Avg('checkin__rating')
).aggregate(
    all_users_avg_rating=Avg('rating'),
    number_of_users=Count('pk')
)
```

This will return a dictionary with *two* elements: `all_users_avg_rating` will map to the average of these averages, and `number_of_users` will return the number of *distinct* users.

---

> **Note**: It is normally better to make use of the [**`settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-AUTH_USER_MODEL) to refer to the user model, than to use the [**`User`** model <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User) directly. For more information you can see the [*referencing the `User` model* section of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model).